# Android add partial layout inside layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this fragment layout where some content needs to be animated (like showing/hiding input field).

Now I found out I could manage this by using a fancy animation (by using `<item name="android:animateLayoutChanges">true</item>` on a linear layout).

The problem I have here is that I need to add al content programmatically..

**For example**

```
    LinearLayout timesheetsWrapper = (LinearLayout)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.new_timesheet_wrapper);
    EditText timeSheetName = new EditText(getContext());
    timeSheetName.setHint("Name");
    timesheetsWrapper.addView(timeSheetName);
```

Now image I need to add like 10 GUI components and style each one of them programmatically, which is a bit of a hassle to me.

Is there a way that I could add a partial layout .xml file into the 'wrapper'?

For instance:

```
LinearLayout partialLayout = ...??
timesheetsWrapper.addView(partialLayout);
```

Where the **partialLayout.xml** contains all the GUI components.

Already searched around but it all got a bit confusing to me!

I hope my question is a bit clear, if not (or additional info is needed) I'am happy to edit/provide.

Thanks in advance, regards an android noob

Comment: `LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.partial_layout, timesheetsWrapper, true);` will add it to the wrapper, assuming `this` is some subclass of Context.

Comment: @zgc7009 sorry of the late response. This is actually working, thanks for that!